# Timer in javascript

Tags: javascript, timer

I have to do a timer in javascript with timing events, the time units should be in milliseconds.

i need something like this:

`start_timer
//some code..
stop_timer
//and then show the ms`

sorry for my english, and thank you for help!

edit:

i tried this method as test:

```
var d = new Date();
    var time =  d.toLocaleTimeString();
    var myVar = window.setInterval(function(time){  time -= d.toLocaleTimeString()
    return code.value = time.toString();
    }, 5000);
```

Comment: I think OP might mean benchmarking, like `console.time()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **console.time** method is perfect but if you want to keep the result in memory you have to use the **Date.now** method.

```
let now = Date.now();

for (let i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    // ...

// Result in milliseconds.
let result = Date.now() - now;

// If you want to show it in a input box.
input.value = result + "ms";
```

Comment: what's let syntax?

Comment: @RiccardoRomoli ES6 syntax its pretty much the new var to understand a little more read into javascript hoisting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `console.time()`, for the browsers that support it:

```js
console.time('Stuff')

for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
   // run some code
}

console.timeEnd('Stuff')
```

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, I just started, it is normal that each time you start, the time change?

Comment: Yes; there are many factors that can influence run time on a machine and thus the numbers logged are rarely consistent. They will start to appear more logical if you place some actual code where I had `// run some code`.

Comment: how can i implement the result on a input box in my html? if you see the code i've posted i need to set "code.value" as the result of timer.